# Laravel 4.1 Vendor Directory Config

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

I want to put my **vendor** directory in the `../vendor` folder instead of the **vendor** folder inside my main project's directory.
This is possible and supported in composer, and so my `composer.json` is reflected:

```
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "vendor-dir": "vendor"
},
```

and I also edited my `autoload.php` file

```
require __DIR__.'/../../vendor/autoload.php'
```

but every time I run composer install, I get:

> Script php artisan optimize handling the post-install-cmd event returned with an error.

and I can't even do any php artisan commands - they all come up empty, not even an error message.
When I had the vendor folder in the normal place with the normal config options, everything worked beautifully. So does L4.1 just not support changing the **vendor** directory?

Comment: Have you overwritten some packages?

Comment: No, I have not. They are exactly as they were when they were generated by composer update

Answer (score 2):

edit composer.json

```
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "vendor-dir": "../vendor"
},
```

edit bootstrap/autoload.php file

```
require __DIR__.'/../../vendor/autoload.php'
```

edit bootstrap/start.php file

```
$framework = $app['path.base'].
             '/../vendor/laravel/framework/src';
```

edit ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Optimize/config.php

```
$basePath = $app['path.base'].'/../';
```

then run composer install, you will find vendor dir created ../

```
php artisan optimize -v --force
Generating optimized class loader
Compiling common classes
```

Comment: If you edit anything in vendor/laravel/framework you are just creating big problems for yourself. You'll lose that change every time you run composer update.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, finally figured it out.

In addition to editing composer.json and bootstrap/autoload.php, you must also edit bootstrap/start.php

```
//to this
$framework = $app['path.base'].'/../vendor/laravel/framework/src';
//from this was before
$framework = $app['path.base'].'/vendor/laravel/framework/src';
```